# Prevent sheet from printing unless certain cell is not blank

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to prevent a spreadsheet from printing if a certain cell eg. F23 in the sheet is blank and get a pop up message to state that the cell needs to be filled in. Please advise how to do this.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workbook object has a `BeforePrint` event. Access it from the `ThisWorkbook` code. You would enter code such as below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F23").Value = "" Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox ("Please populate F23")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not prevent the sheet from printing. I have right clicked the sheet in question, clicked on view code and pasted your code in, however by selecting print it still prints the sheet even though I know that the cell value is "". Please advise if I am doing anything incorrect.

Comment: @JohnDavies Don't put the code in the worksheet code. Instead, put it in the `ThisWorkbook` code. To get there, open the VBE (press ALT+F11). On the left of the window, there should be a tree view box titled Project - VBA. Within this treeview, there should be a `ThisWorkbook` module. Enter it there.